# PySide: QtGui.QFileDialog - UNC Path issue

Tags: python, qt, unc, qfiledialog

Is there any way to select an UNC path (\something) via the QFileDialog? getExistingDirectoy() wont work for me (Windows7). Or is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: unfortunately Qt does not support UNC :(

Comment: yea i figured ;) the funny thing is it doesnt seem to have a problem with a subfolder of an UNC root folder.
For Example selecting \\root wont work but selecting \\root\subfolder works just fine